# Mysql 'greater than(>)' query always returns 0

Tags: mysql, date, compare

I am working with a query where I want to display number of upcoming dates. The following query returns 0 even though there are dates greater than current date. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
SELECT  (case when b.booked_date > cast(now() as date) then sum(1) else sum(0) end) as upcoming_booked_facilities                           
        from    svk_apt_book_facilities b   
        where   b.customer_id = 1
                and b.association_id = 1        
                and b.is_active = 1
        group   by b.facility_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum a `CASE` expression to do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    facility_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN booked_date > CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS upcoming_booked_facilities
FROM svk_apt_book_facilities  
WHERE
    customer_id = 1    AND
    association_id = 1 AND
    is_active = 1
GROUP BY
    facility_id;
```

You were trying to use the sum as the predicate of the `CASE` expression, which is probably not what you want.  Note that I am also selecting the `facility_id`, since you are grouping by that column.  If you instead want a conditional sum over the entire table, then don't select or group by facility.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working fine. I have grouped by facility_id because I want the count of upcoming dates with respect to individual facilities.